Use LINQ to convert flat list of X, Y into IEnumerable<Point>
I have a flat list of strings.  The values are a series of sequential XY pairs.  So
X, Y, X, Y, X, Y
etc..
I want to write a LINQ statement to transform these into an IEnumerable<Point>  (specifically System.Windows.Point) without creating an intermediate list.  It seems I should be able to do this with some combination of Skip, Take, even SelectMany but my LINQ-fu is middle of the road and I cannot figure out how to do it.
The best I've been able to come up with is a function enumerator.  And I can live with this if I must.  But is there a LINQ way?  (At least one that wouldn't be much slower?)
using System.Windows;
...

private static IEnumerable<System.Windows.Point> EnumeratePoints(IReadOnlyList<string> list)
{
    var numPoints = list.Count / 2;
    if (list.Count % 2 != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid # of points");

    for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
    {
        var idx = i * 2;
        yield return new Point(double.Parse(list[idx]), double.Parse(list[idx+1]));
    }
}


You can convert your for loop into an LINQ expression using Enumerable.Range() as follows:
var points = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length / 2)
    .Select(i => new Point(double.Parse(list[2*i]), double.Parse(list[2*i+1])));

Its similar to Svyatoslav Danyliv's answer, but will work with older framework versions. It also avoid the creation of an intermediate array for each coordinate pair (as noted by Joe in the comments).

I like both answers but it seems like this would be slightly more performant as it does not need to copy the two values to an array every time.  Granted it's the same array but it still seems like it would generally be snappier

You can use Chunk extension method.
var result = list.Chunk(2)
    .Select(p => new Point(double.Parse(p[0]), double.Parse(p[1])));


Typo in that answer, should be => not = as per:
var result = list.Chunk(2)     .Select(p => new Point(double.Parse(p[0]), double.Parse(p[1])));

Here is the English Chunk() documentation.

@TN, missed that this in ru ))
